# Moon, center of mass & geometric center, tidal locking

Tags: the-moon, tidal-forces

Since the moon is tidally locked to earth, what about center of mass and geometric center? How far from each other are they? Can a celestial body be tidally locked to an other one if its mass distribution is perfectly homogeneous (center of mass at the very same place of geometric center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the moon is tidally locked to earth, what about center of mass and geometric center? How far from each other are they?

They differ by about two kilometers.

> Can a celestial body be tidally locked to an other one if its mass distribution is perfectly homogeneous (center of mass at the very same place of geometric center)?

Yes, but that condition is not what I would call "perfectly homogenous". What's needed is a non-spherical mass distribution. For example, a uniform density ellipsoidal body would have its center of mass and center of figure of coinciding, but would still be subject to torques. It's the moment of inertia that is key rather than the offset between center of mass and center of figure. An object whose center of mass and center of figure do not coincide necessarily has a non-spherical moment of inertia tensor.

Comment: To add to this, it's the tidal bulge, not the moon's gravitational irregularity that lead to the tidal locking.   A gravitational irregularity rotates around in circles.  A tidal bulge stays in one place ahead of or behind the straight line between the Planet and Moon.   That's not to say that the gravitational lumpiness has no effect.  It has some.  But the tidal bulge has a much greater effect in most tidal locking situations.

Comment: @userLTK -- If you are writing about the Earth's tidal bulge, this (a) would have zero impact on a spherically symmetric Moon and (b) [doesn't exist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121830/does-earth-really-have-two-high-tide-bulges-on-opposite-sides/121858#121858). The Moon, however, does have a frozen tidal bulge.

Comment: I was talking about how the tidal bulge in general is the feature that leads to tidal locking, not gravitational asymmetry.    I thought that was relevant to the homogeneous question.

Comment: @DavidHammen I don't believe that tides don't exist for a second. There are multiple issues I have with the answer you linked. Besides, if you just look around the web, you'll see extremely varying answers and opinions about tides so its a really hard thing to get a straight, correct answer on. Kind of like the question about what makes planes fly.

Comment: @zephyr - I never wrote tides don't exist. I wrote that the tidal bulge doesn't exist. Laplace wrote pretty much the same thing when he came up with his dynamic theory of the tides.

Comment: Okay, tidal bulge instead of tides then. My claim still stands. I don't believe that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @zephyr - Humanity has been measuring the tides for centuries, including recently with extremely accurate orbiting radar altimeters. They don't see those bulges. They instead see Laplace's [amphidromic systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphidromic_point). Newton's tidal bulges are a bit of a [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). While the concept explains the tidal forcing function nicely, it does not explain what happens on a rotating planet partially covered with a thin veneer of water. Laplace's theory does, and it doesn't have a bulge.

Comment: @DavidHammen Now I have to call you out. Are you talking about tides or tidal bulges! Tidal bulges 100% exist. That's just plain math and application of physics. I can agree that the tidal bulge may not always correspond to tides in the ocean for a variety of reasons like ocean currents, topology, etc. but the tidal bulge most certainly does exist. How could you explain the Moon moving away from the Earth, for example, if the tidal bulge did not exist? Furthermore, your linked question stating tides can't travel through water fast enough is faulty for the reasons one comment pointed out.

Comment: @zephyr - Yes, tidal bulges exist. The Moon has them. It has a mostly frozen set of bulge that wobble around a bit due to the eccentricity of the Moon's orbit. the solid Earth has them, but diminished because of elasticity in the solid Earth tides. These smallish tidal bulges and their time variations are hard to see, but they're their. The oceans on the other hand do not have the bulges you were taught about in high school or college. They cannot exist and they are not observed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62557/discussion-between-zephyr-and-david-hammen).